# Plot a shape on a specific value and time

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I want to plot a shape (any shape) on a specific value on a specific time. For example, I want to plot a shape on EURUSD with value 1.02903 on 30 Nov 2022 12:00. How do I do that from pine script? Thanks

I was trying to use plotshape and label but not getting what i want.

Comment: Welcome to SO. "I was trying to use plotshape and label but not getting what i want." - If you may provide more information on how you were doing this? code snippet, etc? it'll help others to help you faster.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `timestamp()` for your specific time and plot your shape with `location=location.absolute` if you want to place the shape at a specific price.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

t = timestamp(2022, 11, 30, 12, 00, 00)
tim = time == t
val = 1.02903

plotshape(tim ? val : na, location=location.absolute, size=size.huge)
```

[image]

Comment: This solution will only work if the timeframe of the candles matches your timestamp. In the example provided, the timestamp is conveniently set at midday, which will match 1-minute, 5-minute, 15-minute, hourly data and so on, but keep in mind that if the timestamp were something like
`t = timestamp(2022, 11, 30, 12, 26, 00)` then that will only plot a shape in the 1-minute chart, because all others will skip over it, and nothing will plot. 
See this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72998932/how-to-plot-arrows-to-show-my-buy-and-sell-data-points-on-tradingview-using-pine)

Answer (score 0):

In order for you to plot any shape on a specific value at specific time, you have to compare the open (`time`) and close (`time_close`) times of any given bar to make sure that your specific time falls within. This will ensure that your shape will be visible on any time frame (1min, 5min, 15min, 1h, 1D...):

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

t = timestamp(2022, 11, 30, 12, 00, 00)
val = 1.02903

plotshape(t >= time and t < time_close ? val : na , location=location.absolute, size=size.huge)
```

Reference: Pine Script documentation on [time variables](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/concepts/Time.html#time-variables)